# Days between two dates error code in python

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import date

f_date = input("Enter your first date: ")
l_date = input("Enter your last date: ")
a = date(f_date)
b = date(l_date)
main = (a-b)
result = (main).days
print("Result: ",result)
```

My first input: `2011/11/17`

My second input: `2011/11/24`

the output that I want is = `7 days`

but I got output : TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

**What should I do to fix this error and get the true output?**

Comment: `input` returns a string, you'll need to parse it to datetime object to do the arithmetic. [docs (datetime)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime), and especially [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: @MrFuppes how? would give me the code?

Comment: He already gave it to you.  Replace `date(f_date)` with `datetime.strptime(f_date, "%Y/%m/%d").date()`.

Comment: `"2011/11/17"` would e.g. be parsed to datetime with formatting directive `"%Y/%m/%d"`

Comment: @Samwise bro I got another error : AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'strptime' .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python parse datestring to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681032/python-parse-datestring-to-date)

Comment: @MrFuppes my English is not that good and I am so amatuar in coding . you mean I have to change the inputs? (I should not do that) . would give me more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the string to a `datetime` with a specified format, for example:

```
from datetime import datetime

f_date = input("Enter your first date: ")
l_date = input("Enter your last date: ")

a = datetime.strptime(f_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
b = datetime.strptime(l_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

result = (a-b)

print("Result: %d days" % result.days)
```

->

```
Enter your first date: 2020-12-20
Enter your last date: 2020-12-02
Result: 18 days
```

Comment: Thank U very much

Comment: bro one more question if I want to have one input what should I do? input : 2020-12-20 , 2020-12-02

Comment: use `.split()`, bro,  `f_date, l_date = input("Enter your two dates: ").split(" , ")`

Comment: or just do it all at once: `a, b = (datetime.strptime(d.strip(), "%Y-%m-%d") for d in input("Enter your two dates: ").split(","))`